# while true loop works perfectly when run manually but gets stuck when run at startup

Tags: bash, while-loop

I have a problem with this while true loop on my RPi. I want it to always wait for user input right after startup. The following script works perfectly when I run it manually:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
  read input
  if [ "$input" = "1" ]; then
    echo "message1"
  elif [ "$input" = "2" ]; then
    echo "message2"
  elif [ "$input" = "3" ]; then
    echo "message3"
  else
    echo "error"
  fi
done
```

But when I run the script at startup by adding it to rc.local it doesn't wait for input. Instead it just echoes "error" infinitely. I don't get it. Why does it work when run manually but gets stuck when run at boot?

Thanks!

Comment: When startup scripts are running, they don't have their input connected to the console.

Comment: See https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1602381

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot wait for user input in a shell that is not connected to a terminal.  Startup scripts are not executed in an interactive shell, so what you are seeing is to be expected : `read` fails, returns an empty string, and causes the `else` condition to be reached.

Maybe what you really want is to call your script from a shell's startup script so that it is presented to the user upon logging in.  Look at the documentation of your shell/disto to know which to use.

You may want to add something like this at the beginning of your script:

```
[ -t 0 ] || exit
```

`[ -t 0 ]` returns 0 if standard input is connected to a terminal.  Please be aware that if the script is sourced rather than executed in its own shell, "exit" will cause the shell performing the sourcing to exit: you may want to put your code inside a function and use `return` instead of `exit`, or use the test as the condition of an `if/then/fi` block containing the rest of the code.

Also, a `case` statement might be more readable than cascading `elif` clauses.

Comment: Thank you! Running the script from .bashrc did the trick! And I'll definitely look into using the 'case' statement instead of 'elif', thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

As @Fred mentions, your command will fail to its purpose, mainly because the script isn't connected to any interactive terminal at all.

The reason why it doesn't work should be clear by understanding the `rc.local` file: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/rc-local.md. The script, that way, would execute whenever the Pi boots. You want it to execute at every user prompt, though. And it works in your already interactive shell because it is well-written and very very correct –– Yay!

Besides all the good advises from @Fred, you should try, if you want to read some **user** input, to include your script inside your `.bashrc` file, which is the file that gets interpreted any time the user (pi, as default there, in `/home/pi/.bashrc`) gets into an interactive shell.

And if what you want is to make it *globally*, when *any* user logs in interactively, you could add it to the "global" `.bashrc`. For further reading on this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36762 Or better yet! check this out: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/profile.html

And finally, about the script itself: as it is a simple `while` loop which uses `read` to get some user input (and, again, @Fred is right about the `case` statement), it can be stopped by signaling the `read` process, for example, using control-C (^C). So, just if you wanted to catch those signals, you should see `help trap` (example: `trap 'echo "YOU WON'T STOP ME"' INT KILL TERM` wouldn't let you use ^C to kill a process –– use it with care), and to list the possible signals, use `kill -l`.

Comment: Be careful : normally `.bashrc` is invoked every time the shell is started interactively, including when not a login shell.  This means that what is in there is executed when you launch Bash from within an interactive session, which may (or probably may not) be what you want. See here : https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files.

Comment: Thank you as well for your additional hints and those really helpful links! Everything working nicely now! :)